# Java Spring - MySQL Connection works, but path will not set

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Learning to connect MySQL DB to Spring and I am running into issue. I can run the application and it compiles with no errors but it does not map the paths properly. I created an Entity that connects to the table in the DB - additionally, I can confirm the MySQL database is working properly as I can pull data from this table using DBVisualizer.
 Errors below -

```
                    2017-11-11 16:32:53.619  INFO 7274 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
                    2017-11-11 16:32:53.622  INFO 7274 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Any ideas?

Below is my Controller..

```
            @RestController
            @RequestMapping(value = "/people")
            public class PersonController {

                @Autowired
                PersonService personService;
                @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                public List<Person> findAll() {return personService.findAll(); }
```

Comment: Show how you have configured your controller in `-servlet.xml` file?

Comment: In the pom file?

Answer (score 0):

I could say your retrieved data is okay. Please check your JSON converter.
Convert Object to JsonString Response.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    converters.add(converter);
}
```